# Cannot create controller in VS 2012 MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I create new project, create a new control have no problem. But when I'm using TFS in Visual Studios 2012 to get the latest code. All code is update, I cannot create new controller. This is my alert error from VS

> could not load file or assembly'System.web.mvc, vesion = 3.0.0.0,culture = neutral, pulbickeytoken = 31bf3856ad364e35' or more of its this system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a missing reference to System.Web.Mvc. Got to the "References" part of your project and add the missing reference.

Alternatively you could add the relevant [System.Web.Mvc.Extensions Mvc 4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Mvc.Extensions.Mvc.4/) NuGet package which should add all references that your solution might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discrepancy in your question between the error and your tag of MVC-4. So assuming you are aiming to use MVC 4.

In Visual Studio, go to the **Package Manager Console via Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.** and run the following commands with the source : nuget.org as answered by [Shiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325521/shiva) in a [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110253/can-i-go-back-to-ef5) question.
**Edit:**

1. **Uninstall** the previous version of MVC 3.0 and all references to it.

   Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mv -Force
2. **Upgrade** to MVC [4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/4.0.30506) to match the tag you've added to the
   question

   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.30506
3. **Check** that [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110253/can-i-go-back-to-ef5) is installed. Check the project file (*.csproj, *.vbproj) references by Right clicking the project file and opening it in a text editor such as notepad++.
4. **[Rebuild or Clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095901/difference-between-build-solution-rebuild-solution-and-clean-solution-in-visua)** (optional) your project. When you have a full compile of the project such as getting the code from TFS, it will check all the references and throw this exception. When you compile the project again this error will most likely not appear as you are not doing a full compile.
5. Check the TFS version of the project file for any discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, the cause was a "Security Update". After this update Project references to System.Web.Mvc.dll are no longer resolved because the assembly version of System.Web.Mvc.dll was incremented.

There are two ways to solve this issue, by installing a nuguet package or by manually updating the reference to System.Web.MVC.dll (don’t use the one in the GAC)

This blog post contains a detailed explanation:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx